# What’s the best way to discover all variables a Perl application has currently defined?

Tags: perl, metaprogramming, metadata

I am looking for best, easiest way to do something like:

```
$var1="value";
bunch of code.....
**print allVariablesAndTheirValuesCurrentlyDefined;**
```

Comment: I think Data::Dumper might be able to do this, but I don't know how.

Comment: brian speaks truth.  The best answer is "don't" followed by "why did you want to do that?"

Comment: brian/Schwern, sounds like there is a new question there,"meta programming rights and wrongs". Can you point me to some questions or links on when and why is "reflection" like this a bad idea. Basically I'd just like to wrap some existing perl with some new perl with no change to the existing app

Comment: There are uses for this.  For example, I have to write some perl code which is executed on a remote machine, and called by some other perl scripts.  In this case I get no debugging information and must "find out" what variables I have access to from my script.

Comment: or you may be debugging, for example, and would like to dump all variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Package variables? Lexical variables?

Package variables can be looked up via the symbol table.  Try [Devel::Symdump](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::Symdump):

```
#!/path/to/perl

use Devel::Symdump;

package example;

$var = "value";
@var = ("value1", "value2");
%var = ("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");

my $obj = Devel::Symdump->new('example');

print $obj->as_string();
```

Lexical variables are a little tricker, you won't find them in the symbol table.  They can be looked up via the 'scratchpad' that belongs to the block of code they're defined in.  Try [PadWalker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PadWalker):

```
#!/path/to/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use PadWalker qw(peek_my);

my $var = "value";
my @var = ("value1", "value2");
my %var = ("key1" =>  "value1", "key2" => "value2");

my $hash_ref = peek_my(0);

print Dumper($hash_ref);
```

Answer (score 7):

The global symbol table is `%main::`, so you can get global variables from there.  However, each entry is a typeglob which can hold multiple values, e.g., $x, @x, %x, etc, so you need to check for each data type.  You can find code that does this [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=181783). The comments on that page might help you find other solutions for non-global variables (like lexical variables declared with "my").

Comment: And don't forget about all the other packages which have variables in scope too!

Comment: +1, but please also mention that lexical variables (those declared like "my $x;") aren't listed in %main:: or anywhere else. :(

Comment: +1, however there's no way to guarantee the link you provided will always work.  Even if perlmonks lives on forever, the site could be reorganized.  It might be worth-while to put some info about using `%main::` in your response.

Answer (score 6):

The [PadWalker](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PadWalker/PadWalker.pm) module gives you `peek_my` and `peek_our` which take a LEVEL argument that determines which scope to look for variables in:

```
The LEVEL argument is interpreted just like the argument to caller.
So peek_my(0) returns a reference to a hash of all the my variables
that are currently in scope; peek_my(1) returns a reference to a hash
of all the my variables that are in scope at the point where the 
current sub was called, and so on.
```

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use PadWalker qw/peek_my/;

my $baz = "hi";

foo();

sub foo {
    my $foo = 5;
    my $bar = 10;

    print "I have access to these variables\n";
    my $pad = peek_my(0);
    for my $var (keys %$pad) {
        print "\t$var\n";
    }

    print "and the caller has these variables\n";
    $pad = peek_my(1);
    for my $var (keys %$pad) {
        print "\t$var\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Nathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735386/whats-the-best-way-to-discover-all-variables-a-perl-application-has-currently-de/735431#735431) is part of the story -- unfortunately, the rest of the story is that lexical variables aren't listed in `%main::` or anywhere else (at least anywhere accessible from Perl -- it's probably possible to write some hairy XS code that digs this information out of Perl's C-level internals).

Lexical variables are what you would normally use for "ordinary local" variables.  They are declared like:

```
my $x;
```

Comment: Luckily, someone has already written the hairy XS code for us.  See PadWalker on CPAN.

Comment: @Chas: Interesting. Although I would feel dirty ever using PadWalker ;)

Comment: In production code? never.  In dev code, no problem.  Think of it as a programmable debugger, in fact, I believe it is used by Devel::ebug to provide the watch variables.

Comment: @Chas: I totally agree. Definitely a useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Would this be for anything other than debugging purposes? If not, you may want to familiarize yourself with [perl's debugger](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pl-deb.html). Once inside the debugger you can inspect all variables by issuing 'V'.

Comment: no, not so much for debugging, it would be part of "dynamic" runtime loading and then figuring what got loaded