# Perl: Dump all live data

Tags: perl, memory-leaks

I am trying to identify a possible memory leak in GNU Parallel which is written in perl.

I can see the maximal memory usage (using `time -v`) increases linearly with the number of jobs, and is somewhat dependent on the length of the command:

```
# Very long command line
$ seq 10000 | time -v parallel true <<50000 x's here>> 2>&1 | grep --colour=auto --colour=auto 'Maximum resident set size'
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 20936

# Short command line
$ seq 10000 | time -v parallel true 2>&1 | grep --colour=auto --colour=auto 'Maximum resident set size'
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 18692

# Few jobs - short argument
$ seq 1000 | time -v parallel true  2>&1 | grep --colour=auto --colour=auto 'Maximum resident set size'
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 16224

# Few jobs - long argument
$ seq 1000| perl -pe '$a="x"x50000;s/$/$a/' | time -v parallel true  2>&1 | grep --colour=auto --colour=auto 'Maximum resident set size'
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 18448
```

At 10000 jobs it is hardly a problem, but at 1000000 jobs it starts to be.

How do I identify what is taking up the extra space? Can I dump all data that Perl think is live when GNU Parallel exits? I have the feeling that simply by going through the live data, I will know if there is a leak or if the extra memory usage can be explained.

I have tried [What’s the best way to discover all variables a Perl application has currently defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735386/what-s-the-best-way-to-discover-all-variables-a-perl-application-has-currently-d) but it does not find all variables, that I know exist; such as this example:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use PadWalker qw(peek_my);

$Global::var = 17;

my $hash_ref = peek_my(0);
print Dumper($hash_ref);
```

Comment: In that question you linked to, you need to pay attention to the fact that PadWalker is for lexical variables, and there are other answers for package variables like `$Global::var`

Comment: What is the `stdout` command?

Comment: stdout is simply a way of saying  `2>&1` without having to quote shell chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This helped me identify the culprit:

```
use Devel::Symdump;

my $obj = Devel::Symdump->rnew();
my @sysout;

for my $v ($obj->scalars()) {
    push @sysout, length(Dumper(eval ('$'.$v)))." \$$v\n";
}
for my $v ($obj->arrays()) {
    push @sysout, length(Dumper(eval ('@'.$v)))." \@$v\n";
}
for my $v ($obj->hashes()) {
    push @sysout, length(Dumper(eval ('%'.$v)))." \%$v\n";
}
print sort { $b <=> $a } @sysout;
```

Comment: So was there a memory leak after all?

Comment: Under certain conditions: Yes. It will be fixed in next release.